# Get query parameter from URL through Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an application need to parse the parameter from URL. But the URL got special character '#'.

URL: http://localhost:8080/test.html?parms=PESTL4#2

I printed the windows.location, and the result is  "http://localhost:8080/test.html?parms=PESTL4#2".

I used the following sample code to get **parms**, and it returns PESTL4.
How does it work?

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.search` returns query string `?parms=PESTL4` without `#2` first line removes '?'.

and then split query string to pairs so `name=joe&age=18` to `['name=joe','age=18']`

in `for loop` it splits string to `key` `value` `name=joe` to `['name','joe']`.

and if first (`name`) equals `variable` return the second `joe`

Answer (score 0):

All that you need are places in `document.location` object.

[**Localiton Object Documentation**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As in their example: [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery)

```
var tech = getUrlParameter('technology');
var blog = getUrlParameter('blog');
```